# Refer to position on page php

Tags: javascript, php, html, reference

I'm making a social media with html, php and javascript. Right now i'm implementing a like function, so when you click on the like button it goes to a php function and it adds a like. But when the php function refers back to the page of posts, it refers to the top of the page. Is there a possible way to refer back to the liked post?

Thank you!

Comment: as much as i hate to say it, you should probably be using AJAX for the like button- then you never have to leave the page

Answer (score 1):

As Dagon said, using AJAX (Preferably jQuery AJAX to make it easier for you) would be the best option. Here's a small snippet:

like.php (POST):

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConn.php'; //File that contains the database bridge, let's pretend $bridge is the bridge

if ( !isset($_SESSION['userid'] ) // We verify the user is logged in, by making sure we can access his user ID
    $error[] = 'Not logged in';

if ( !isset($_POST['post_id'] ) ) // We verify that a post ID was provided
    $error[] = 'Error, no post ID was provided';

if ( !isset($error) )
{
    $query = $bridge->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '".$_POST['post_id']."' LIMIT 1"); //Assuming you're using MySQLi

    //I'm going to pretend that there's a column called LIKERS and that each liker is separated by two colons

    $data = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $likers = explode("::", $data['likers']);

    $likers_str = $data['likers']; //We'll use this later

    if ( $query->num_rows < 1 ) // We make sure the post exists
    {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => "The specified post does not exist"));
    }
    else
    {
        if ( in_array($_SESSION['userid'], $likers) ) //We find out if the user has liked the post already
        {
            echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => "You have already liked this post"));
        }
        else
        {
            $query = $bridge->query("UPDATE posts SET likes += 1 WHERE post_id = '".$_POST['post_id']."' LIMIT 1"); // Add the like
            $query2 = $bridge->query("UPDATE posts SET likers = '".$likers_str."::".$_SESSION['userid']."' WHERE post_id = '".$_POST['post_id']."' LIMIT 1"); // Add users to likers list

            if ( $query && $query2 ) //We verify both queries were successful
                echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "errors" => null));
            else
                echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => "There has been an error while liking this post"));
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => implode(", ", $error)));
}
```

like.js (AJAX):

```
$(document).ready(function() //Assuming you use jQuery
{
    $(".likeButton").on('click', function() //Click on like button
    {
        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "like.php",
        data: { post_id : $(this).attr('id') }, //We grab the post id from the button
        dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            if ( data.success == "true" )
                alert('Post liked'); 
            else
                alert('Error, could not like post: ' + data.errors);
        });

        //After executing it I'd recommend disabling the button
    })
});
```

Then, if you're curious on how to create the button, it should be created as such:

```
<div class="likeButton" id="postid, something like 39128535">Like</div>
```

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you're awesome :) But i have one question, is it possible to make a javascript function for the like button witouth jQuery? I'm not able to use it :(

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with raw JavaScript, I however believe you can use the html `onclick` event and call a JavaScript function from it, then use `XHR` (Ajax) to do the PHP part. You can start [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when you click the like button, pass a `GET` parameter (`like.php?liked=#id1`) and then, just redirect back with the id at the end of the url:

```
$hash = $_GET['liked'];
header("Location: where/likes/are.php{$hash}");
```

The `#id1` should be the DOM id of an element where you want your page to be scrolled at.

Note that this is just a rough example. But I strongly recommend to use AJAX in order to perform this kind of procedure.